# Using multiple RIA silverlight links with shared server side entities

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, entity-framework, ria

For a project I'm using Silverlight 4.0 with RIA and EntityFramework 4.0. I have three web projects:

- Common.Web: contains general types
- Workflow.Web: contains domainservices for workflows
- Monitor.Web: contains domainservices for monitors

Both the Workflow.Web and Monitor.Web project uses a Enumeration (SalesChoice) type defined in the Common.Web project as return value on a DomainService.

So far the Web side of this story. We continue with the client part, which consists of two projects:

- Workflow.UI: Contains the RIA connection with the Workflow.Web
- Monitor.UI: Contains the RIA link with the Monitor.Web

Now my problem (finally :) ). In the Workflow.UI project I need to use information from the Monitor.UI project, so I added a reference between those two. When I build the project I get an error:

**Warning as Error: The type 'MyProject.SalesChoice' in 'Generated_Code\Workflow.Web.g.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'MyProject.SalesChoice' in 'Monitor.UI.dll'.**

It is pretty easy to explain why it's going wrong, but I'm looking for a solution. Maybe my whole approach with a shared Common.Web project is not possible or the best idea?

Answer (score 0):

(sorry for my bad english) 
On this cases I prefer to use a [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx). Define your enum on that project and add it as reference to all projects where you need it.

Comment: But that won't help right? RIA will still generate the type because it's the return type of a webservice call.

Comment: Hum, good question - I did a test here (created a method on my domainService returning the portable library enum) and on my generated.cs on silverlight side it did not generated another type, it was using the portable library one (I was surprised) - so I guess it will work on your case. Did you tried it?

Comment: That would be a nice sophisticated piece of programming if it would use the portable type. I'll try this afternoon. However, even if it does work, I'm afraid we are not yet allowed to use PCL in our production environment :(